# Apache test page is loading instaed of application index page

Tags: php, linux

In my project, I am using a Linux server and the whole application is built in PHP but a few days ago I tried to access the application by typing the URL in the address bar but it's loading the apache index page instead of the application index page
what to do to solve this issue?
it's loading
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Test Page instead of the application index page

[image]

Comment: Two possible reasons: 1. You're not putting the PHP files in the correct folder (make sure it's the folder Apache has configured as document root). 2. You haven't removed the default .html file. In a default configuration, `index.html` (and/or possibly `default.html`) is configured with higher priority than `index.php`, meaning that if there is both an `index.html` and `index.php`, the server will use `index.html`. Read more about the [DirectoryIndex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html) directive. It will check the order from left two right, using the first match.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, seems to me like you have incorrectly set up the `server environment`. Keep in mind that when you submit a `GET request` to an `apache server` via its public IP address, you will get the contents of its `htdocs` folder. If that folder has an `index.html` file, that will take priority over any `index.php` file unless you explicitly tell it otherwise.

On another note, it is also a common practice to create a virtual server for each website on your actual server even if you only deploy 1 website. Go to your `sites-available` folder and create a file with the name of your website (e.g. `www.google.com`). There you can set up your virtual server. Here is a basic template you can follow:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have an SSL certificate, you also put the paths to it here. You will need a rule for different ports in that case (443) as well. It is best to set your server up for 80 and then use a tool like `certbot` which will take care of everything else for you and even take care of automatic monthly updates to the certificate.

This is assuming you have a domain and an A record for that domain (if youre using one). If not, replace the `ServerName` with the IP address of the server.

Edit: Here is a good resource for Apache vhosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Edit 2: Another note - notice the url of the link I provided. the first part (httpd) is an a record tied to the domain. The domain is apache.org. The part before the `://` defines the protocol and everything after `apache.org/` specifies path to a file in the directory which is defined as `DocumentRoot` in the virtual server. I hope this clears things up if you are new.